# After adding volley on Android studio Gradle sync failed

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have problem with adding `volley` on Android Studio.
After adding `volley` on Android Studio`, when I sync the gradle project it says:

```
Error:Connection timed out: connect. If you are behind an HTTP proxy, please configure the proxy settings either in IDE or Gradle.

gradle sync failed: Connection timed out: connect. If you are behind an HTTP proxy, please configure the proxy settings either in IDE or Gradle.

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

I tried the below method: http settings in `gradle.properties`

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=www.somehost.org
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.http.proxyUser=userid
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=password
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost
```

but it didn’t work.

Answer (score 0):

Try **Invalidate Caches and Restart**.

Goto File->Invalidate Caches/Restart->Choose "Invalidate and Restart".

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your machine is connected to the internet.
2. Go to **File** -> **Settings** & expand **Build, Execution, Deployment** -> **Gradle** -> UNCHECK **Offline work** -> OK
3. **Disable** all **proxy** settings for your project & also remove proxy http settings from `gradle.properties`
4. Go to **File** -> click on **Invalidate Caches / Restart** -> **Invalidate & Restart**